# Shoot problem with Oculus Go after recenter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

i try to make a VR Game with unity and Oculus Go.
You can shoot with the Oculus Go controller and it works if i dont recenter the camera. If i recenter my Camera, the bullets fly in the wrong direction.
For my controller, i have a line renderer. This works perfect.
Anyone has an idea why that is?
gunBarrel is an child object of my controller
sorry for my bad english!!!

```
        if (OVRInput.GetDown(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))
        {
            GameObject bulletTmp = Instantiate(bullet, gunBarrel.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            bulletTmp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gunBarrel.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 150);
            bulletTmp.transform.LookAt(gunBarrel.transform.position, Vector3.up);
            return true;
        }
```